# xt4 on usb flash for transfering files

Tags: permissions, mount

I have 2 PC's with ubuntu. I want to transfer files between them using a flash drive. The only possible way (so far) is to use ms's fs (ntfs or fat) on the flash drive.

Question is: how to set permissions on an xt4 partition so that will be automounted rw by a user in both PC's (a user which have the same user name and user ID)?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of "sneakernet" file transferring is done all the time.  Ubuntu will easily mount rw a USB thumbdrive that has a fat format.  This assumes that the data on the TD is rw of course.

The ability to mount, read and write to files on a TD are irrespective of the user, assuming that the user is not expressly denied access to USB storage.

I presume you are asking about formatting a TD in EXT4 format.  To accomplish what you want (manually transferring files from one machine to another), using a MS fat formatted USB storage device will work perfectly well.

You might consider using Filezilla to sftp files back and forth.  It's trivial to setup, is faster and a lot easier.

Comment: Assuming there is a local network, the tip about filezilla is good: install openssh-server in one of the computers and connect via ssh, sftp or with a nicer user interface using filezilla from the other computer to 'get' or 'put' files. (You can even use the regular file browser for this purpose.)

Comment: Question is still how to set permissions. Whenever there is a network connection available I just email them (even by setting a local emailer).